# In SharePoint 2013 how can I set up a Two-Way Auto Sync connection between 2013 excel file and sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am using Sharepoint 2013 , and there is a excel(2013) file with in the Sharepoint. I want to create a list by using some columns in the excel sheet, so after creating the list i want two way sync between the list and excel file ... i.e if i make any changes in list should appear in excel file and viceversa. Is there any way to do this? please comment your views.

Answer (score 2):

> There are several ways to synchronize data between a SharePoint list
>   and a spreadsheet program. Whichever way you choose, this
>   synchronization is **one-way, or unidirectional**. Changes made in the
>   SharePoint list can be written to the spreadsheet program, but any
>   changes that you make in the spreadsheet program are not written to
>   the SharePoint list.
>
> To synchronize a SharePoint list, you must have a compatible
>   spreadsheet program, such as Excel 2013, installed on your client
>   computer, and you must have read permission to the list.

[Synchronize a list with a spreadsheet program](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Synchronize-a-list-with-a-spreadsheet-program-bfb2ea48-6118-4fa9-abb6-cced9424e5d9?CorrelationId=224309eb-0160-4990-9fa1-26aa333b1f7a&ui=en-US&rs=en-NZ&ad=NZ)

But to over come this, You can use **add in** called “Synchronizing Tables with SharePoint Lists”. What the add in does is it allows us to synchronize a SharePoint list with an Excel file.

Read complete here:http://sharepointrhapsody.com/2013/04/02/connecting-an-excel-sheet-to-sharepoint/

Comment: Thank you Waqas for your response, i am using ADD IN but it  is not working fine with excel 2013. is there any chance to write a code behind in visual studio and deploy to make this sync work?.